# Toggle menu disappears instantly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

By clicking toggle button I am just able enough to see the menu  (which I have set on toggle button)  only for a quarter of a second and then disappear. I am new in bootstrap. I may have made some very obvious mistakes. Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container ">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark bg-dark">      
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png">The building co.</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item" > <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home </a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" > <a href="#" class="navbar-link">contact us </a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" > <a href="#" class="navbar-link">policy </a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" > <a href="#" class="navbar-link">terms </a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" > <a href="#" class="navbar-link">About us </a> </li>          
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you made any changes in the CSS?

Comment: not yet. I am just using bootstrap classes without making any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have the exact starter template according to bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After that just put **bootstrap navbar component** links according to the bootstrap [documentation sample](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/).

Comment: Thank you sir it works :). but I am not able enough to know where was the actually error.

Comment: @Danishmahmood When dealing with javascript always it's important to place scripts at the bottom of the page as they block rendering while they're being loaded and executed. You can read these [guidelines](https://browserdiet.com).

Answer (score 1):

You are either missing or using incorrect path to `bootstrap.min.css`. Once that is corrected your code works:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container ">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png">The building co.</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home </a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">contact us </a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">policy </a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">terms </a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">About us </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```